# convert: Postscript delegate failed from .Net(ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert a PDF to image with Imagemagick. I installed both imagemagick and ghostscript But when run from within .net(Asp.Net MVC), gives the following error:

Magick: Postscript delegate failed `C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PDF\Page0001.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/713

This is my code

```
MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
            settings.Density = new MagickGeometry(300, 300);

            using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {
                images.Read(@"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PDF\Page0001.pdf", settings);

                MagickImage horizontal = images.AppendHorizontally();
                horizontal.Write("Snakeware.horizontal.png");

                MagickImage vertical = images.AppendVertically();
                vertical.Write("Snakeware.vertical.png");
            }
```

Source : [Source](http://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20PDF&referringTitle=Documentation)

Error Comes

```
 images.Read(@"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PDF\Page0001.pdf", settings);
```

From this line.. 
Does Anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: GhostScript is not creating output images or they could not be read. Have you tried getting more information by [enabling debugging](https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Detailed%20debug%20information&referringTitle=Documentation)?

Comment: It gave same error  in Image.Read

Comment: Can you add a link to your PDF and are you using the latest version of Magick.NET and Ghostscript. Feel free to also start a topic here: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions.

Comment: Thanks Buddy.. I'll do it